# OneDrive SDK Upload folder

Tags: sdk, directory, onedrive

I am looking to upload a WP8.1 application's data folder to OneDrive for backup and syncing across devices.  Is there a way to upload, and download, an entire folder and subfolders without having to enumerate thru each item individually?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this functionality is not provided with the [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK), which is the OneDrive 3rd party interface.

Answer (score 0):

Although the LiveSDK does not allow this function automatically, your app does have access to its own special folder in OneDrive.

If you're using the latest OneDrive SDK (NOT the Live SDK) in C#, you can use the following code:

```
string[] scopes = { "wl.signin", "onedrive.appfolder" };
var OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
await OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
var appRoot = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
```

At the end of it all, your appRoot item is the app's very own special folder. You may then upload your individual files into the folder for storage, or download if you determine the online version to be more recent.